# Hibernate. Analog of Query#setParameterList

Tags: java, hibernate

I have native SQL query in Hibernate:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table where id IN (:ids)
```

I want to substitute `:ids` named parameter with `List<Long>`.

```
Query query = query.createSQLQuery(...)
query.setParameter( "ids", ids, ???); // WHAT Hibernate type to use here?
```

What type should I use as 3-rd parameter of `setParameter` method?

For example for Boolean I used this one and it worked (but didn't work without specifying type):

```
query.setParameter( "active", active, new NumericBooleanType());
```

Please note, I can't use `Query#setParameterList` (because my list can be `null`)

**EDIT:**

Actually my query looks more like this:

`SELECT * FROM my_table where :ids IS NULL OR id IN (:ids)`

it's help me to support optional parameters without need to dynamically creating SQL (which is code smell I think). And if my `List` is empty, I'm replacing it with `null` because SQL does not allow an empty IN clause (if it `null`, then the `OR id IN (:ids)` section will not be executed at all in my case).

So I'm using `setParameter` only because it allows to use `null`s, but `setParameterList` throws exception when collection is `null`.

How I can cause `setParameter` to work just like `setParameterList` but without throwing exception?

Comment: to the best of my knowledge, you can't, setParameter is for a single value, setParameterList is for multiples, and you're trying to do both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't use setParameterList, you must dynamically create the SQL with n substitution params and call setParameter() on each.

SQL in general does not allow an empty IN clause, so you'll need to handle that case separately.